# Module not found: Can't resolve '../typings' in '/vercel/path0/pages'

Tags: typescript, deployment, vercel

I was deploying my next js website using vercel. But it stucks here. Help me out please.

tried to delete node_modules folder and the package-lock.json and run npm intall again but didn't fixed that problem :/

Comment: Not sure how we can help without further information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, use the `git config core.ignorecase false` command in your local environment and then commit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using git, make this command `git config core.ignorecase` false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).